# Capture values from sections in file :Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

```
# line 1 contains some info
# line 1 contains some info
# Creation date: Tue Aug 16 17:13:37 2016

# line 3 contains some info
# line 4 contains some info

DEFAULT_TEMPLATE
{
    DELAY_TIME        30;
    TEMPLATE_FNAME    "ABC";
    VENDOR_DELAYED    "/";
    DELAY_FNAME       "ABC_NAME";
    DELAY_FVALUE      "DELAYED-30";
    DELAY_FMODE       "END";
}

TEMPLATE
{

  2548                # some-details1
  {
    DELAY_TIME        0;
    DELAY_FNAME       "DSPLY_NAME";
    DELAY_FVALUE      "DELAYED-0";
    DELAY_FMODE       "END";
  }

  1                   # some details2
  {
    DELAY_TIME        20;
    DELAY_FNAME       "DSPLY_NAME";
    DELAY_FVALUE      "DELAYED-20";
    DELAY_FMODE       "END";
  }

  2                   # some details3
  {
    DELAY_TIME        20;
    DELAY_FNAME       "DSPLY_NAME";
    DELAY_FVALUE      "DELAYED-20";
    DELAY_FMODE       "END";
  }
}
```

I have file format like above and i want to capture detail from only "TEMPLATE" section and from each section under "TEMPLATE" i want to get numbers (like 2548,1,2) which are at the start of each section and value for  "DELAY_TIME" (which is currently 0,20,20) in python .

Comment: Looks like you also want to write some code.

Comment: Can you modify the file format using yaml or json ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex:

**Ex:**

```
import re
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    data = infile.read()

template = re.search("^TEMPLATE[^.]*", data, re.M).group()
print(re.findall("\s+(\d+)\s+", template, re.M))
print(re.findall("\s+(\d+)\;", template, re.M))
```

**Output:**

```
['2548', '1', '2']
['0', '20', '20']
```